# curl doesn't work in bash loop

Tags: linux, bash, curl

I run this command in a single bash file to post the data to a url and get the response

```
curl  -s -X  POST $url -d "username=username"
```

It outputs the response body. All good
But I want to automate this task so I have saved many URLs in a file called urls.txt which looks like this:

```
https://url1.com
https://url2.com
and so on...
```

To loop all the lines(url's) in the file I run this script

```
while IFS="" read -r p || [ -n "$p" ]
do
  curl -s -X  POST $p -d "username=username" >> output.txt
done < urls.txt
```

I even try to run the loop with a hardcoded url, and it still doesn't work:

```
while IFS="" read -r p || [ -n "$p" ]
do
  curl -s -X  POST http://manual.url -d "username=username" >> output.txt
done < urls.txt
```

But I get no output saved or displayed. I don't know why is that. Any ideas? Can't I run curl in a snoop-a-loop?

Comment: What happens if you remove the `-s` ("silent") option and don't redirect into a file? Do you get the correct output in the terminal? What if you properly put the URL last on the command line and double quote it?

Answer (score 1):

You read the lines into a variable named `p`, but this is not used afterwards.

I would do it like this:

```
while IFS='' read -r url || [ -n "$url" ]; do
    echo "URL: >>$url<<"
    curl -s -X  POST $url -d "username=username" >> output.txt
done < urls.txt
```

Comment: I just edited it to $url for users to understand easier. But in fact in the code I have a problem its $p 

Still doesnt work 
Blank response even with your code

Comment: I edited to echo the read URL. You don't see that either?

Comment: There is no issue with `read -r url || [ -n "$url" ]`, this is a common way to read lines from files whose last line is not properly terminated by a newline.

Comment: @Kusalananda Thanks! Learned something. Thought it is to filter out empty lines.